# is there a stable Note 3 mod utilizing S-pen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-note-3, s-pen

Is there a stable Mod that does not compromise on the S-pen of Note 3?
Since a mod could better utilize the raw power of the device.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a "Mod"? If [our Mods](http://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) were "not stable", we'd know about. I also didn't hear they compromised some pen ;)

Comment: I never went near mods hearing about phone bricking, didnt want to risk my note 3. But this morning I completely dissembled the note 3 to fix the volume buttons...  So i was like what the heck,  lets get some mod!  But i love the spen integration with snote, scrapbook and Evernote.  So was wondering if its worth modding??

Comment: So you're talking about Custom ROMs I guess? Because a "mod" is quite broad. Besides from being a synonym to "moderator" (see my link above ;) it simply means "modification", so it could be everything from an app via a simple patch up to a fully customized ROM like OmniROM or CyanogenMod.

Comment: Yes custom rom, is there one rom that will be so good for my phone,  that a new android programmer like me will be awestruck enough so as to start programming mods for the next five years?!!  ;)

Comment: Please take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575) then :)